# Error using an object for implementing an empty List

Tags: collections, kotlin

I'm trying to rewrite the List interface as an exercise for learning Functional Programming in Kotlin, but I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting an error when I'm trying to have an object as the empty list, that doesn't occur in the Kotlin standard library. In my code, see below, I want to use NIL as a singleton empty list, using list() as the function to return it. However, this generates a type mismatch error on the function of type "Required List. Found NIL"

```
interface List<A> {
    val empty: Boolean
    val head: A
    val tail: List<A>

    fun cons(a: A): List<A> = Cons(a, this)
}

object NIL : List<Nothing> {
    override val empty: Boolean = true
    override val head: Nothing
        get() = throw IllegalStateException("head called on empty list")

    override val tail: List<Nothing>
        get() = throw IllegalStateException("tail called on empty list")
}

private class Cons<A>(override val head: A,
                      override val tail: List<A>) : List<A> {
    override val empty: Boolean = false
}

fun <A> list(): List<A> = NIL // Type mismatch. Required: List<A>. Found: NIL

fun <A> list(vararg a: A): List<A> {
    var n = list<A>()
    for (e in a.reversed()) {
        n = Cons(e, n)
    }
    return n
}
```

In the standard library, this error doesn't occur, as you can see in [EmptyList in Collections.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L33). Am I doing something wrong or am I missing some concepts that make the latter possible and the former not?

### Evaluating Proposed Solutions

Of the three solutions proposed, the only one that allows passing the test code below is the one using the **anonymous object**, while the others throw the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Void`.

```
assertEquals("a", list<String>().cons("a").head)
```

However, if I change `NIL` to `NIL : List<Any?>`, the solution `NIL as List<A>` works without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can cast a `List<Nothing>` to a `List<A>` explicit by `as` keyword, for example:

```
fun <A> list(): List<A> = NIL as List<A>;
```

**IF** you want to suppress the compiler warnings, you can annotated the function with `@Suppress` annotation, for example:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <A> list(): List<A> = NIL as List<A>;
```

**OR** if you don't like this way, you can using [an anonymous object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) in a funtion instead, for example:

```
fun <A> list(): List<A> = object : List<A> {
    override val empty: Boolean = true
    override val head: A
        get() = throw IllegalStateException("head called on empty list")

    override val tail: List<A>
        get() = throw IllegalStateException("tail called on empty list")
};
```

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. Of your suggestions, only the anonymous object allows passing the test without any exception.

Comment: @gmariotti because you using `Nothing` for the `NIL` . replacing `Nothing` with `Any?` that everything is ok. maybe this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) can help you. and the third approach will create a new object instance for each call that you can test with : `assertNotSame(list<Int>(), list<Int>());`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that. At this point, which solution do you think is more idiomatic? IMHO, the first one, considering it doesn't have the problem of creating a new object every time.

Comment: @gmariotti if you familar with java, [generic type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) only occurs at compile time.

Comment: @gmariotti that is clearly, the first approach is effectively than the last, but it is a little ugly. even if java uses it everywhere, for example: [Collections#emptyList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#4420).

Answer (score 2):

Generic on your interface should be `<out A>` instead of `<A>`.

Also, IntelliJ Idea shows a warning when you use generics without out variance in such cases.

Comment: But then should I use the `@UnsafeVariance` notation for implementing methods like `contains(element: A)`?

Comment: Yes, you can read more about that case here - https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-1-0-beta-candidate-is-out

Comment: However, the use of @UnsafeVariance doesn't allow to perform operations as in test I have posted in the update to the question.